# Sorting and taking average in textfile

Tags: matlab

I have two text files like this:

**File1.txt**

```
Size   Iterations
3        45
5        6
7        50
1        34
5        56
1        4
```

**File2.txt**

```
Size   Iterations
3        5
5        6
7        6
1        3
5        6
1        4
```

I want to do two things first:

1) Sort the two files on the basis of size.

**File1.txt**

```
Size   Iterations
1        34
1        4
3        45
5        6
5        56
7        50
```

**File2.txt**

```
Size   Iterations

1        3
1        4
3        5
5        6
5        6
7        6
```

2) Once the files get sorted on the basis of size then I want to create a new file and store the average of all the iterations corresponding to each unique size number

like this:

```
Size  Average
1      3.5  
3      5
5      6
7      6
```

I am new to MATLAB. Please guide me which functions to follow to achieve the above task.

Comment: I don't get how you produce the _Average_ values based on _Size_ and _Iterations_ !! or whether they are related or not!!

Comment: Are the rows tab separated or not?

Comment: @Mohammad I want to take the  average of all the iterations corresponding to each unique size number

Comment: So this would be (34+4+3+4)/4 which is equal to 11.5. You better edit your question.

Comment: @phyrox they are three space separated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presumed that the first raw in *file1.txt* and *file2.txt* do not exist. I mean those lines which contain ASCII characters.

```
clear all
a = load('file1.txt');
b = load('file2.txt');
c = [a;b]; % appends file2 below file1

[aa I] = sort(c(:,1)); % you can find sorted IDs in I
ids = unique(c(I,1));
ave = zeros(1,ids);
for i=1:length(ids)
    currentIds = I(c(I,1) == ids(i)); %boolean indexing in sorted IDs
    ave(i) = mean(c(currentIds,2));
end
disp([ids,ave'])
```

Comment: It works great. Can you please explain how the average is computed in this code.

Comment: This is pretty simple! Inside _for_ loop we have: a Group of indexes which belong to _i_th _Size_ is specified from vector _I_ which contains sorted indexes. Now indexes of rows of _i_th Size which exist in _currentIds_ leads us to calculate the mean value. This is possible by indexing _c_ matrix.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code:

```
%1-Sort everything
s1 = tdfread('File1.txt','   ');%Three space separation
[sorted_s1_size,sorted_s1_idx]=sort(s1.size,'ascend');
sorted_s1_iterations = s1.iterations(sorted_s1_idx);

s2 = tdfread('File2.txt','   ');
[sorted_s2_size,sorted_s2_idx]=sort(s2.size,'ascend');
sorted_s2_iterations = s2.iterations(sorted_s2_idx);

%2-Get the average

sizes = [sorted_s1_size;sorted_s2_size];
iterations = [sorted_s1_iterations,sorted_s2_iterations];

unique_sizes = unique(sizes);
avg_iterations = zeros(1,length(unique_sizes);
for i=1:length(unique_sizes)
  w_size = unique_sizes(i);
  w_idx=find(sizes==w_size);
  avg_iterations(i) = mean(iterations);
end

%4-Write the file
fid = fopen('output.txt','w');
for k=1:length(unique_sizes)
   fprintf(fid,'.2f\t%.2f\n',unique_sizes(i),avg_iterations(i));
end
fclose(fid);
```

You can optimize it removing the two sorting operations (as `unique` also sorts by id).